# Display Rows if Column Value is repeated

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table that looks like this:

```
DATA             | TEST_ID | PARAM_ID
-------------------------------------
c:\desktop\image1| 11      | 1
c:\desktop\image2| 12      | 1
c:\desktop\image3| 13      | 1 
c:\desktop\image4| 14      | 1
Fail             | 14      | 2
0.45             | 14      | 3
c:\desktop\image5| 15      | 1
Fail             | 15      | 2
0.68             | 15      | 3
c:\desktop\image6| 16      | 1
Fail             | 16      | 2
0.25             | 16      | 3
```

I would like to create a query where the result only shows DATA if TEST_ID has the same value repeated 3 times.

Ideal Result:

```
DATA             | TEST_ID | PARAM_ID
-------------------------------------
c:\desktop\image4| 14      | 1
Fail             | 14      | 2
0.45             | 14      | 3
c:\desktop\image5| 15      | 1
Fail             | 15      | 2
0.68             | 15      | 3
c:\desktop\image6| 16      | 1
Fail             | 16      | 2
0.25             | 16      | 3
```

Would the best approach be to use COUNT(*)>2 for the TEST_ID column?

Comment: Use window `count() over()` if your DBMS supports it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by test_id) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt >= 3;
```